# How to make list and thumbnail view

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a web application in which I list a lot of movies, by now I load a thumbnail for each one of them, but when the list of movies is very largue the page stays loading and loading. So, I'm thinking on offer to ther users 2 views: thumbnail view and  list view (this one is for faster loading).

So, which options do I have to achieve this? I ask this questions because there are some topic to consider as:

1.-I can make 2 views and hide one or another (listview or thumbs), but, in the case that the user chooses **list view** how do I prevent that the pages even stays loading the hidden images? (or should I leave it in this way?)
2.-Is good to have 2 panels (one for every kind of view) and just hide a show? or normally how is it done?

I want to make it very clean, understandable and optimized. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use regular `<img>` tags, and convert them into a list under certain circumstances such as the user choosing to display them as a list or too many loading (or *any* given JavaScript condition):

```
$('img').each(function() {
  var img = $(this),
    src = $(img).attr('src');
  $(this).replaceWith($("<li><a href='" + src + "'>" + src + "</a></li>"));
});
```

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/fey8a39b/).

Note that this works by targetting the DOM elements themselves, so it doesn't actually need to wait for the images to finish loading before converting them to links.

Hope this helps!